# Nativescript navigation is terribly slow

Tags: performance, angular, angular2-routing, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have implemented angular route navigation in nativescript, and I am experiencing poor performance, which I cannot seem to find a bottleneck for.

This is the current setup

```
┌──────────────────┬─────────────────┬────────────────┬───────────────┐
│ Component        │ Current version │ Latest version │ Information   │
│ nativescript     │ 2.3.0           │ 2.3.0          │ Up to date    │
│ tns-core-modules │ 2.3.0           │ 2.3.0          │ Up to date    │
│ tns-android      │ 2.3.0           │ 2.3.0          │ Up to date    │
│ tns-ios          │                 │ 2.3.0          │ Not installed │
└──────────────────┴─────────────────┴────────────────┴───────────────┘
```

The repository can be seen here:
https://github.com/felipemullen/teras

You can see it's a very simple structure that is based on the example repository.
However, a transition from one page to another takes about ~3-4 seconds, which is really bad.

Here are a couple screenshots to show how simple the app is, there is barely any binding, and no data is being loaded. All that happens is one button leads to another page:

[image]
[image]

So the question is, **why do these pages load so slowly?** Is this simply because nativescript is still so young? I played with the demo apps, and they don't seem to have this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The slow navigation is due to this issue:

https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2735

It is already fixed in the "@next" builds and will be included in the official `2.4.0` release after 1-2 weeks.

Comment: UPDATE: Switching over to 2.4.0 fixes things and is awesome, specifically build "2.4.0-2016-10-19-4474". On the other hand, "next" built "2.5.0-2016-10-21-4514", which at this point is generating an android exception on the exact same codebase, somewhere at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative. For this reason, I recommend using 2.4.0 until an official release is out

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be some issues with 2.3.0, I switched to `"tns-core-modules": "next"` in package.json () which seems to make it a bit better but there is certainly work to be done in this area.